# D3: Translating two identical paths so that they run parallel

Tags: math, d3.js, coordinates, coordinate-systems

My question is as follows:

(a) I am plotting two paths in D3 that have exactly the same coordinates. The same paths.

(b) I would now like to transform one of the paths so that they run parallel and that the 'width' between the paths is always equal to x pixels. My code is as follows:

```
d3.select("#path2")
.attr("transform", "translate(15,0)");
```

Unfortunately, the code yields the following:

[image]

As you can see the lines are not parallel and are intersecting. In fact it's a bit of a dog's breakfast. I have a feeling this could be alot more complicated than it sounds to achieve. Or is it? Any ideas?

Thank you all

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? I ran in to a similar problem recently

Comment: Will do as soon as I can grab my computer! Did you overcome your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a different approach to propose: create two identical paths, like you're doing right now. Then, if you want a distance of, for instance, 16px, set the `stroke-width` of one of the paths bigger than that and use the other path as an [SVG mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask), with a `stroke-width` of 16, at the very **same** position of the other path.

That way, one path will make a "hollow space" in the other one, without any complicated math.

Here is a demo. I put a circle just for showing that the path is hollow:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")

var dataset = [
    [0, 30],
    [20, 30],
    [50, 55],
    [60, 70],
    [100, 120],
    [110, 90],
    [135, 121],
    [200, 70],
    [300, 130]
];

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d[0];
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d[1];
    });

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 200)
    .attr("cy", 70)
    .attr("r", 30)
    .attr("fill", "teal")

var defs = svg.append("defs");

var mask = defs.append("mask")
    .attr("id", "pathMask");

mask.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 150)
    .attr("fill", "white");

mask.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(dataset))
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", 16);

var path = svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(dataset))
    .attr("mask", "url(#pathMask)")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 20)
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
</svg>
```

If you don't need a transparent fill, the solution is even easier: draw two paths, one over the other, with different `stroke-width`, and fill the upper one (with the smaller stroke width) with the same colour of the background.

Comment: This is clearly the best way to do it. Thanks Gerardo, apologies for the while it has taken me to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to say that each segment of the 'parallel' path should be parallel to the corresponding segment of the original path. So, for each segment of the original you compute a parallel line, the given distance away, and then intersect successive lines. You should choose the directions, that is the normals to the line segments, consistently; for example be computing the normal direction as a 90 degree clocwise rotation of the tangent direction in each case, or as an anticlockwise rotation in each case.

In nice cases -- where the angles between successivve segments are small and the distance small compared with the smallest segment length -- this may well give yu what you want. In other cases you'll get a mess.